Kong API Gateway Open Source on docker with https
I'm facing a configuration issue while setting up Kong API Gateway (Open Source Edition) in a containerized environment.
Following the official Kong documentation, I used the commands below to set up Kong:
Network Creation:
docker network create kong-net

PostgreSQL Container Setup:
docker run -d --name kong-database \
--network=kong-net \
-p 5432:5432 \
-e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
-e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
-e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kongpass" \
postgres:13

Database Bootstrap:
docker run --rm --network=kong-net \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kongpass" \
kong/kong-gateway:3.7.1.2 kong migrations bootstrap

Kong Gateway Setup:
docker run -d --name kong-gateway \
--network=kong-net \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" \
-e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kongpass" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL=http://localhost:8002" \
-e KONG_LICENSE_DATA \
-p 8000:8000 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-p 8001:8001 \
-p 8444:8444 \
-p 8002:8002 \
-p 8445:8445 \
kong/kong-gateway:3.7.1.2

While this setup works, and I can access the Kong Manager on port 8002, I'm having trouble enabling HTTPS. When I change the manager URL to https://localhost:8445, the GUI shows a CORS error when trying to access the Admin API on port 8444.
How can I properly configure HTTPS for the Kong Manager without encountering CORS issues?
The CORS plugin is not the solution because it should be related to the API endpoint.
I've tried several things like removing the

KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL

parameter, but nothing seems to work.

Have you tried adding the Kong HTTPS port to the admin listen environment variable? -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl"

Yes, it's the default behaviour. Of course the admin interface in https exists, the problem is that the manager instance is on a different port causing a CORS error.
The latest kong version does not support the *.

Well, checking the documentation (and securing admin api reference), that doesn't appear to be the default behaviour: if you don't set KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN to also include "8444", the admin API won't be reachable via HTTPS (therefore, the Kong Manager won't be able to retrieve the configuration information from the HTTPS endpoint). But that's probably not 100% related to your CORS issue.

Exactly, the admin interface exists, the CORS issue is a different problem.

can you show your cros error here, which is the key factor

If you dont set ADMIN_GUI_URL then Kong will use whats requested in the browser i.e. https://localhost:8445 admin_gui_url
BUT the catch comes in with the admin API, ADMIN_GUI_API_URL - the docs say this admin_gui_api_url

Hierarchical part of a URI which is composed optionally of a host, port, and path at which the Admin API accepts HTTP or HTTPS traffic. When this config is disabled, Kong Manager will use the window protocol + host and append the resolved admin_listen HTTP/HTTPS port.

The issue is not the hostname or the protocol because this is taken from your Manager request but the port. Because admin API runs on port 8444 and Manager off 8445 you need to specify this. The same goes if you are using DNS and they are different subdomains you need to tell Kong that.
So you adjust your config you need to use the following
docker run -d --name kong-gateway \
--network=kong-net \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" \
-e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kongpass" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL=https://localhost:8445" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_GUI_API_URL=localhost:8444" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8444 http2 ssl"
-e KONG_LICENSE_DATA \
-p 8000:8000 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-p 8001:8001 \
-p 8444:8444 \
-p 8002:8002 \
-p 8445:8445 \
kong/kong-gateway:3.7.1.2

Once you are running the containers, because its a certificate the browser doesnt trust you will need to go to https://localhost:8444 and trust the cert and then go to https://localhost:8445 and trust the cert again and Manager will now work over SSL.
I have tested the above docker command and it works.

This. I think OP is overlooking some relevant information, because it's impossible to have the GUI not showing "Network Error" with that setup... Kong Manager Network Error

Thanks for your comment @mikyll98 but I have tested the above config on my laptop right now and it works without a network error. Have you tested this out yourself?

You misunderstood my comment :) I'm saying that with the same configuration that OP (@docdev) provided, Kong Manager can not work on 8445, because the Admin API HTTPS endpoint (8444) is not exposed. I've not tested your exact configuration but I suppose it will work, since you seem to be setting the env variables correctly

I tried different commands, and the key was to trust the self-signed certificate on both endpoints. I didn't realize that a CORS error could occur from not trusting a self-signed certificate.

Based on your configuration, changing KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL and KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN to allow ssl should be enough:
    docker run -d --name kong-gateway \
    ...
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL=https://localhost:8445" \
    -e KONG_LICENSE_DATA \
    ...

There shouldn't be CORS error unless there is something more to this setup.
Just to recheck, have you trust the self-signed certificate on both https://localhost:8444 and https://localhost:8445?
If no certificates are provided, Kong will create two self-signed certificate, one for Admin API and one for Manager.
This might cause the network error on Kong Manager  since the browser doesn't trust Admin API certificate when using the GUI (Kong Manager).
